# Android: How to Stop service that is started by bindService() with BIND_AUTO_CREATE option?

Tags: android, service, bind

I start service by using:

```
private ServiceConnection _serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {...}
bindService(new Intent(this, MainService.class), _serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

I want to 'restart' the service. (Let's not argue why I want to do that)
I do that by:

```
unbindService(_serviceConnection);
// Do some initialization on service
bindService(new Intent(this, MainService.class), _serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

I noticed service doesn't die(onDestroy doesn't run) until I call next bindService();
So some static initialization I did on service got cleared by onDestroy() implementation.

Question: How do you make sure unbindService() will stop service (run onDestory()),
so that I could do initialization after and re-run bindService()?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Android keeps services around at it's own discretion, even after calling `unbindService` or `stopService`.

If you need to immediately reinitialize some data on the service side, you most likely need to provide a service method for doing that.

Answer (score 5):

> Question: How do you make sure unbindService() will stop service (run onDestory()), so that I could do initialization after and re-run bindService()?

The timing of `onDestroy()` after the last `unbindService()` is indeterminate and certainly asynchronous. You could also try calling `stopService()` yourself, but that too is asynchronous, so you don't know when it will be stopped.

I do not know of a reliable way for you to "restart" a service using the binding pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can use onRebind() if you return true in onUnbind().

see here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html